# Badge for questions asked for a week

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

Is there any badge for more questions asked ?,lets say i have asked 10 questions in a week - Out of the none is closed or moved to another SO affiliate site.Do you guys award a badge for these type of guys to encourage more questions?

Comment: To all those down-voters ,please leave a comment.Down-voting without a comment is against SO rules.

Comment: @Srinivas - there's no such rule that you have to comment when downvoting - voting is anonymous.  On meta an upvote often means 'agree', while a downvote means 'disagree', especially on feature requests.  Doesn't reflect on the quality of your post.

Answer (score 10):

I disagree with such badge, as it will cause people to ask the first question that comes to mind, just to get the badge.

Better request for similar badge might be "Asked five or more questions rated 5 or higher", but even such thing is unlikely go get implemented.

Edit: more than three years later, [I stand corrected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges). Kudos to the team!

Answer (score 5):

There's plenty of incentive for asking good questions already:

- Well asked questions are more likely to get good answers
- You might earn a little reputation from your peers
- If many people view the question, you can get a badge
- If you get enough up-votes, you can earn a badge

Stack Overflow doesn't have a problem with question quantity, more with *quality*.  The number of questions posted per day is rising.  Some say that the number of good questions per day is not rising at the same rate.

Comment: I know all this,i am asking for badge for q's asked for a week..

Comment: @Srinivas - I don't see the point.  The badge and reputation systems are designed to encourage behaviour that will benefit the site.  Perhaps a badge for a number of questions of a certain quality might be ok - but 'not closed' isn't really a sign of quality on its own.

Answer (score 4):

No there is no badge for that. And I would be surprised if it was implemented.

Badges are to encourage behaviour and as long as the majority is answered in a satisfying way (and that fact is known by enough people), the questions keep comming.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any badge for more questions asked?

**Yes, now there are badges for more questions asked.** By maintaining a positive question record and asking well-received question on X separate days, can give you following badges:

[image: Curious] Asked a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintained a positive question record.

[image: Inquisitive] Asked a well-received question on 30 separate days, and maintained a positive question record.

[image: Socratic] Asked a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintained a positive question record.

A positive question record is defined as:

> (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5

A well-received question means:

> A question that's open, not deleted, and has a score > 0. If you ask
>   at least one well-recieved question in a UTC day and none of your
>   questions that day are deleted, downvoted, or closed, you get one more
>   day of credit toward the badge.

Reference: [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges)