# How can you track community reputation?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting, area-51, metrics

**There are lots of metrics on how well a Stack Exchange Community is doing**

- Visits per day
- Questions per day
- Answers per question

One issue with these metrics is they are all traffic dependent and hard for a community to fix on our own.

I am part of the [3D Printing Stack Exchange Beta](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/), and we have problems with getting traffic (which as I mentioned is hard to fix); but, another problem I have noted of late is that reputation is painfully hard to grow. This is mostly because there are very few up votes on questions and answers (even good ones).

Here is a list of our top questions. Note that even the TOP QUESTION often get no votes or at the most just a few - even though they sometimes have over 100 views.

[image: Top 3D questions]

One of the [most viewed questions](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11/how-do-i-give-3d-printed-parts-in-pla-a-shiny-smooth-finish) in our community had **over 3700 views** and had **just 34 up votes**. That is better; but, still pretty low compared to both the view count and the response a top question would receive on other communities.

The reward system that is baked into Stack Exchange is **reputation** and much of reputation comes from good questions and answers. Much of this is determined by **votes**.

This would be a lot easier to track and address if there was a way to see the issue, have a goal, and track our progress.

**Is there a way to track either total reputation or total votes for all the users of a community?**

---

Without upvotes and reputation progress, it can be very discouraging to people that put the time and effort into asking and answering good questions. If we want to grow our community, we need to put more effort into hitting the up arrow every time we think that a question or answer was worth the read.

**Good questions and answers are what fuels the community and reputation is a good indication of that.**

**It would be a big help to have a fuel gauge to watch to remind people that we are (or aren't) paying our fuel bills.**

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you really ask for, beyond all the (correct, but not really relevant) background. You want live gauge that shows the sum of reputation of all users in a site?

Comment: Yes, I want a way by which I can track either the total reputation or votes cast on the site/community.

Comment: My underlying question is "how do I get people on the site (especially the leadership) to upvote questions and answers more".  Should change it to that instead?

Comment: I doubt "reputation gauge" will help with that. Badges are more likely to help, e.g. see [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134084/could-we-have-badges-targeting-goals-unique-to-beta-sites).

Comment: If you have the site analytics privilege, you should be able to track voting traffic from there.

Comment: It's kind of a [**catch-22**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)) since without reputation you can't do much and if no one votes it is almost impossible to get any reputation.

Answer (score 2):

According to [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/3dprinting/query/703884/reputation), your total reputation is 286k and the average is 43. Note that that includes users like me who are registered on the site, have 101 reputation because of the association bonus, but aren't really active.

A [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) Meta post (on your site's own Meta) to stress the importance of voting might help. Some beta sites have had one at their start, called "Vote early, vote often".

Comment: I'm on mobile right now; feel free to use it as a starting point for a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, SEDE looks Really Cool.  I am going to have to play.

Comment: Regarding a Meta post, already [**posted one**](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241/why-are-there-so-few-votes) over a week ago to no avail.  No comments or answers.  Even the top users don't seem to vote much and that sets the trend/pattern.  I am not sure how to get out of this rut.  I am certainly getting tired of putting the effort into writing good questions and answers if no one seems to appreciate them.

Comment: That post isn't [featured]; a lot of users don't read Meta or even don't know it exists. You can ask a moderator on your site to make it featured (if they agree).

Comment: I added [a post](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244/featuring-select-meta-posts-so-general-users-see-them) to Meta discuss featuring Met posts.  Can you provide a link of how to do that?

Comment: You'll have to *ask* a moderator on your site to do that, either with a comment (one of them already commented on your meta post) or in chat. You *can't* add this tag yourself.